# How to open .ipynb files in IntelliJ?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, ide, ipython, jupyter

I have IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4 Community edition. I want to open existing .ipynb files however IntlliJ failes to open them as .ipynb but only as txt.

Answer (score 2):

The [Intellij documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/jupyter-notebook-support.html) has a page on Jupyter notebook support. 
On this page you'll find that this is only available when you have the Python plugin installed, which is only supported in IntelliJ Ultimate (and thus not in the community edition).

The same goes for [PyCharm (docs)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html), where notebooks are only supported in the professional edition.